# Можно ли сделать switch в зависимости от знака числа?

Tags: c#, switch

Возможно ли сделать:

```
switch (Dec1-Dec2)
{
  case <0:  ...
  case 0:   ...
  case >0:  ...
}
```

?

Comment: Сделать и проверить намного быстрее, чем сидеть и ждать ответа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
switch (Math.Sign(Dec1 - Dec2))
{
  case -1:  
    ...
    break;
  case  0:
    ...
    break;
  case  1:
    ...
    break;
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Если взять на вооружение C# 8, то можно попробовать сделать нечто подобное:

```
static string SomeMethod(int first, int second) => (first, second) switch
{
    var (f, s) when (f - s) > 0 => "Больше",
    var (f, s) when (f - s) < 0 => "Меньше",
    var (_, _) => "Равны"
};
```

Соответственно будет примерно следующее:

```
SomeMethod(1, 2); // 1-2 = -1. Вывод: Меньше
SomeMethod(2, 2); // 2 и 2.    Вывод: Равны
SomeMethod(3, 2); // 3-2 = 1.  Вывод: Больше
```

Мог допустить неточности, ибо для меня новшества 8 версии в новинку, но суть думаю ясна.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с C# 7 можно использовать следующую структуру для диапазонов и прочих условий:

```
        int asd = 177;
        switch (asd)
        {
            case int z when (z >= 100):
                Console.WriteLine($">= 100: {z}");
                break;

            case int z when (z >= 50 && z < 100):
                Console.WriteLine($">= 50 && < 100: {z}");
                break;

            case int z when (z < 50):
                Console.WriteLine($"< 50: {z}");
                break;
        }
```